# Type safety error with generic class

Tags: java, generics, types, interface, abstract

edit: The setup

There is a parser that call methods from the ProgramFactory, this factory uses Expressions, statements, types and programs as seen in the header for the implementation below.
ProgramFactory implements IProgramFactory which is an interface that looks like this `public interface IProgramFactory<E, S, T, P>`

The problem I seem to have is that Expression is also generic and I do not know how to get that right in the implementation (in the header and in the methods)

It seems to work when only the return type is of type Expression as seen here

```
    @Override
public Expression<Boolean> createTrue(SourceLocation sourceLocation) {
    True expr = new True();
    return expr;
}
```

but not when the variable are also of type Expression

I made it so that the wildcards for the return type and for the argument type do
not have to be the same

```
public abstract class BinaryExpression<T, R> extends Expression<T>{
    Expression<R> left;
    Expression<R> right;
}
```

In the implementation of an interface I seem to have the same problem over and over again.

> ```
> Expression is a raw type. References to generic type Expression<T> should be parameterized
> ```

The problem is when I do parameterize these Expressions they tell me that the interface doesn't have this method.

> ```
> The method createAddition(Expression<Double>, Expression<Double>, SourceLocation) of type ProgramFactory must override or 
>  implement a supertype method
> ```

this is what the implementation looks like

```
@Override
public Expression<Double> createAddition(Expression left, Expression right, SourceLocation sourceLocation) {
    Addition expr = new Addition(left, right);
    return expr;
}
```

this is what the interface looks like

```
/** An expression that evaluates to the sum of the given expressions */
E createAddition(E left, E right, SourceLocation sourceLocation);
```

this is what the class Addition looks like

```
public class Addition extends BinaryExpression<Double, Double>{ 
    public Addition(Expression<Double> left, Expression<Double> right){
        this.left = left;
        this.right= right;
    }

     @Override
     public Double eval() {
         Double sum = left.eval() + right.eval();
         return sum;
     }
}
```

This is what the Expression class looks like

```
public abstract class Expression<T> {
    public abstract T eval();
}
```

This is what the header for the implementation looks like

```
public class ProgramFactory implements IProgramFactory<Expression<?>, Statement, Type, Program>{
```

Comment: There are important bits missing, the interface and class declarations of the first two snippets (`ProgramFactory` and the implementation class)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide full interface implementation. So I can think it's something like:

```
class MyImplementation implements Interface<Expression> {
        @Override
        public Expression<Double> createAddition(Expression left, Expression right, SourceLocation sourceLocation) {
            Addition expr = new Addition(left, right);
            return expr;
        }
}
```

But should be like:

```
class MyImplementation implements Interface<Expression<Double>> {
        @Override
        public Expression<Double> createAddition(Expression<Double> left, Expression<Double> right, SourceLocation sourceLocation) {
             Addition expr = new Addition(left, right);
             return expr;
        }
}
```

This is raw type `Expression = |Expression<E>|`. And using simple `Expression` in your method parameters you erase type parameter. You cannot declare in your interface implementation raw `Expression` and override method using parameters with type parameter(CTE). Think about type parameters like they are simple alias.

Comment: The problem here is that Expression is generic and the implementation uses multiple types of expression, therefore I cannot put Expression<Double> as argument after the interface

Comment: @Goatherder95 You should really describe what the setup is and what you're trying to achieve, as this looks very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If so and you really need such implementation you can declare `Interface<Expression<?>>` and use 
`public Expression<?> createAddition(Expression<?> left, Expression<?> right, SourceLocation sourceLocation)` also you can bound it like `<? extends SomeClass>` or `<? super SomeClass>`. But remember you should also change it in class type declaration.

Comment: The trouble with a wildcard here is that presumably you'd want all three (left, right and the return value) to be of the same type, which is not the case with wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression class should like below,

```
class Expression<T> {
  ....
}
```

Your interface should look like below,

```
@Override
public Expression<?> createAddition(Expression<?> left, Expression<?> right, SourceLocation sourceLocation) {
     Addition expr = new Addition(left, right);
     return expr;
}
```

And also make your Expression class as generic one. create your

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, and also I have already using these kind of structure in my application.

Comment: That's strange because `Expression<?>` will definitely not go into `Expresssion<Double>`, so this line `Addition expr = new Addition(left, right);` should not compile.

Comment: The Expression class is generic

Comment: Yes generic, so i can handle any type of data. like Collection<?> / Collection<Double>. If you mention the type explicitly in generic then it won't accept other types. If you give "?" then it will accept any type. See wildcard generics documentation and Java spec

Comment: But the return value in this case should be Expression<Double>

Comment: this seems to have erased my problem for not

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly parameterise all the arguments in your interface:

```
public interface IProgramFactory<T> {
  public Expression<T> createAddition(
      Expression<T> left,
      Expression<T> right,
      SourceLocation sourceLocation
  );
}
```

Then you can do:

```
public class ProgramFactory implements IProgramFactory<Double>{
  @Override
  public Expression<Double> createAddition(
      Expression<Double> left,
      Expression<Double> right,
      SourceLocation sourceLocation
  ){
    Expression<Double> expr = new Addition( left, right );
    return expr;
  }
}
```